# ¿Por qué decimos una canción es "de" un artista y en cambio un libro es "por" un autor?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones

En Inglés, decimos una canción es "by" un artista y un libro es "by" un autor.

No entiendo la razón de la diferencia en Español.
¿Hay una regla para esto o es algo que sólo tengo que memorizar?
¿Hay una manera de saber cuál usar para una película o algo mas?

EDICIÓN: Recuerdo haber visto esto en un libro (como "Por *nombre*"), pero no puede encontrar un ejemplo.  Google Translate [usa "por" para un libro](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/the%20book%20is%20by%20the%20author).  ¿No es corecto, o que es específico para cada país?

Comment: En mi Español nativo de Colombia uso "de"en ambos casos. (El amor en los tiempos del cólera es de García Márquez) (Paint it black es de los Rolling Stones).

Comment: Concuerdo con @DGaleano. Un libro no es *por* un autor. Un libro *está escrito por* un autor. El *por* es necesario para indicar el agente (el "verdadero" sujeto) porque es una construcción pasiva. Si al referirse a la canción se usara una construcción pasiva (por ej., la canción *está  compuesta por* X), también sería necesaria la preposición *por*. A lo mejor no te has encontrado muchas construcciones pasivas referidas a canciones porque el cantante ya no suele ser el compositor, pero no hay diferencia entre ambas: para ambos casos se usa *de*.

Comment: Se me olvidaba... para las películas es exactamente igual. Ej: "Star Wars es de G. Lucas" y atendiendo la observación de @Yay "Star Wars fué escrita por G. Lucas"

Comment: @yay ¿Le gustaría escribir una respuesta con esa información?

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta de Adrian Cid Almaguer. Puedes aceptar la suya.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coincido con los comentarios generados en la pregunta. Normalmente, cuando usted escucha referirse a "por" un autor se refiere al libro "escrito por" un autor:

> La novela *La Regenta*, escrita **por** L. A. Clarín, es de finales del siglo XIX.

"Por" indica el agente de la acción en construcciones pasivas, y no se limita a libros, sino que también se usa con canciones, películas, etc.:

> *Imagine*, escrita e interpretada **por** John Lenon, es una de las canciones más famosas del músico.

Pero también se suele escuchar que el libro es "de" un autor:

> La novela *La Regenta*, **de** L. A. Clarín, es de finales del siglo XIX.

Así como con canciones:

> *Imagine*, **de** John Lenon, es una de las canciones más famosas del músico.

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de ampliar tu respuesta para que pueda ser aceptada.

Comment: @Yay gracias, igualmente usted pudiera poner su respuesta y ser aceptada dando roolback su edición, no es la intención para mi ganar puntos en este sitio

Comment: No hay de qué. Ni la mía.